# Detener escucha de micrófono

Tags: python

Tengo un problema ya que tengo un microfono economico(y de fondo de escucha una estatica), y por lo que entendi en el codigo sigue escuchando hasta que no se escuche ningun sonido, pero al tener este microfono nunca deja de escuchar, y se que el problema es el microfono ya que al poner el micro en 0, ahi frena la escucha.Por eso lo que quiero es ver si existe alguna manera de hacer que corte la escucha con alguna tecla o combinacion de teclas.

```
    import speech_recognition as sr
    r = sr.Recognizer() 
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Speak Anything : ')

        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

        audio = r.record(source)

        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='es-ES')
            print('You said: {}'.format(text))
        except:
            print('Sorry could not hear')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente cortar la grabación con una combinación de teclas no es tan sencillo. Según como indica la [documentación](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst):

```
`recognizer_instance.record(source: AudioSource, duration: Union[float, None] = None, offset: Union[float, None] = None) -> AudioData:
```

> Records up to duration seconds of audio from source (an AudioSource instance) starting at offset (or at the beginning if not specified) into an AudioData instance, which it returns.

> If duration is not specified, then it will record until there is no more audio input.

Por lo tanto, tienes dos alternativas más a mano.

1. Establecer una duración fija de grabación.

```py
audio = r.record(source, duration=20)
```

2. Utilizar la detección de silencios.

```py
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
audio = r.record(source)
```

Se que ya probaste la segunda, pero tal vez te sirva revisar al documentación, dado que es importante para que funcione que mientras se está calibrando se intente estar en silencio, y también puedes usar el parametro `duration` para intentar tener una buena calibración.